# What's the difference between the following two codes?

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting

I have two codes to find the integer numbers $m$, $x$, $y$, $z$ in the system of equations. 
First code

```
Solve[{( m  x +   y - 7 z)^2 == 
   Cos[\[Pi]/3]^2*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)*(m^2 + 1^2 + 7^2), -10 <= m <= 
   10, -10 <= x <= 10, -10 <= y <= 10, -10 <= z <= 10}, {m, x, y, 
  z}, Integers]
```

Second code

```
Clear[a, b];
a = {m, 1, -7};
b = {x, y, z};
Solve[{Abs[a . b]/(Norm[a] Norm[b]) == Cos[\[Pi]/6], 0 <= m <= 10, 
  0 <= x <= 10, 0 <= y <= 10, 0 <= z <= 10}, {m, x, y, z}, Integers]
```

The first code run faster the second code. I can not get the answer of the second code. How to edit the second code? How do I tell *Mathematica* to do that?

Comment: It would help you to understand your functions better. (Geometrically, $m$ determines a *conical surface* in $(x,y,z)$.) By making a plot it will become apparent that you can limit the search in the second code to `0 <= m <= 10, 0 <= x <= 6, 0 <= y <= 4, 0 <= z <= 10`. For instance, explore the situation with `Manipulate[ContourPlot3D[f[m, x, y, z], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}, Contours -> {0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], {m, 0, 10}]` after defining `f[m_, x_, y_, z_] := With[{a = {m, 1, -7}, b = {x, y, z}}, (a.b)^2 - (a.a) (b.b) Cos[\[Pi]/6]^2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a solution.  If you use a system option to increase the explicit search range such that it applies to this problem:

```
SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> "ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints" -> {10000, 100000}];

Clear[a, b];
a = {m, 1, -7};
b = {x, y, z};

Reduce[{Abs[a.b]/(Norm[a] Norm[b]) == Cos[\[Pi]/6], 0 <= m <= 10, 0 <= x <= 10, 
  0 <= y <= 10, 0 <= z <= 10}, {m, x, y, z}, Integers]
```

> False

Quoting [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DiophantineReduce.html):

> Mathematica enumerates the solutions explicitly only if the number of
>   integer solutions of the system does not exceed the maximum of the
>   p[Null]^th power of the value of the system option
>   DiscreteSolutionBound, where p is the dimension of the solution
>   lattice of the equations, and the second element of the value of the
>   system option ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints.
>
> For systems containing explicit lower and upper bounds on all
>   variables, Mathematica uses exhaustive search to find solutions. The
>   bounds of the search are specified by the value of the system option
>   ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints. The option value should be a pair of
>   integers (the default is {1000,10000}). If the number of integer
>   points within the bounds does not exceed the first integer, the
>   exhaustive search is used instead of any solution methods other than
>   univariate polynomial solving. Otherwise, if the number of integer
>   points within the bounds does not exceed the second integer, the
>   exhaustive search is performed after all other methods fail.

Comment: The first I typed Cos[Pi/3] and the second Cos[Pi/6]. If I change your code is Cos[Pi/6], I only get three solutions.

Comment: @minthao_2011 (I assume you mean change `Cos[Pi/6]` to `Cos[Pi/3]`.) Yes, that's correct.  What's your point?

Comment: You try Solve[{( m  x +   y - 7 z)^2 == 
   Cos[\[Pi]/3]^2*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)*(m^2 + 1^2 + 7^2), -10 <= m <= 
   10, 0 <= x <= 10, 0 <= y <= 10, 0 <= z <= 10}, {m, x, y, 
  z}, Integers]
The number of solutions are more your code.

Comment: @minthao_2011 I'm not understanding you.  Are you proposing that the solutions should be the same?