# Why Reduce command dosn't work in my below code?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I have tried to solve the following equation as shown in the code using `Reduce` command, but I can't solve for the values of `a`, `b`, `p`. with 'p' is a prime number,I used also `FindInstance` command, but I didn't get any result.

Code:

```
Reduce[a^n == b! + p && 50 >= n > 0 && 40 >= a > 0 &&  
  30 > p > 0 && 30 > p > 0, {a, b, p}, Integers]
```

Comment: Your code gave me 172 solutions (Version 13.1, Mac M1): https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmikC.jpg

Comment: @MichaelE2  The unique solutions are (2, 2, 2) and (3, 4, 3).

Comment: What about `a == 12 && b == 3 && p == 6`?  It seems to work (for `n == 1`).

Comment: `v=Partition[Flatten[Table[{a,b,n,p},{a,1,40},{b,1,29},{n,1,50},{p,1,29}]],4];
Select[v,({a,b,n,p}=#;a^n==b!+p)&]` gives 136 solutions, but that includes n in those solutions.

Comment: `Select[Tuples[Range/@{40,29,50,29}],({a,b,n,p}=#;a^n==b!+p)&]` Same 136 solutions. To try to answer the original question, we probably can't ever know why `Reduce` and `FindInstance` didn't work for you. Both have LOTS of algorithms inside and each tries one more more algorithms for any problem given to them. Perhaps the factorial in the problem made the chosen algorithms fail to find a solution. Your space was small enough that brute force searching was able to find solutions for you. It is also unknown why you believe there are only two unique solutions when other people find many solutions

Comment: This shows that all 172 solutions satisfy the equation and conditions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQLTk.png — Note that it takes almost a minute to run, so maybe you did not wait long enough? (I guess it's clear that @Bill gets only 136 because the exhaustive search excludes `n <= 0`, and the `Reduce` code does not. `Reduce` [may be doing an exhaustive search itself](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17896/whats-the-difference-between-the-following-two-codes/17897#17897), after determining the search space.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 The `172` versus `136` worried me and I should have tracked down the exact reason. Is anyone else puzzled and disturbed by the original code stating `Reduce[...&&50>=n>0&&...]` (which is what I based my search on) and yet there are solutions requiring negative `n`?!?! Your testing results includes the constraint of positive `n`. I don't think I've ever seen `Reduce` return a solution that didn't satisfy all the given conditions. Could this perhaps be because `Reduce` isn't returning n in the solution? Is this perhaps a gateway to `Reduce` solutions that we can't depend on? Thanks

Comment: @Bill I guess I'm blind (though I'm slightly dyslexic, and it may be I accidentally switched in the wrong letter). I meant `b <= 0`, not `n <= 0`. Sorry about that. Probably one of the `30 > p > 0` should have a `b` instead. Note that if `b == 1` works, then `b == 0` works, since `b` appears only in `b!`.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik , you have tow times `30 > p > 0 && 30 > p > 0 ` Think one should be a `b` . Please only present us a code you have proofed to be right ! Otherwise you waste our time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Reduce[a^n == b! + p && 50 >= n > 0 && 40 >= a > 0 && 30 > p > 0 && 
30 > b > 0 && p \[Element] Primes, {a, b, p}, Integers]
```

> `(n == 1 && a == 3 && b == 1 && p == 2) || (n == 1 && a == 4 && b == 1 && p == 3) || (n == 1 && a == 4 && b == 2 && p == 2) || (n == 1 &&  a == 5 && b == 2 && p == 3) || (n == 1 && a == 6 && b == 1 &&  p == 5) || (n == 1 && a == 7 && b == 2 && p == 5) || (n == 1 &&  a == 8 && b == 1 && p == 7) || (n == 1 && a == 8 && b == 3 &&  p == 2) || (n == 1 && a == 9 && b == 2 && p == 7) || (n == 1 &&  a == 9 && b == 3 && p == 3) || (n == 1 && a == 11 && b == 3 &&  p == 5) || (n == 1 && a == 12 && b == 1 && p == 11) || (n == 1 &&  a == 13 && b == 2 && p == 11) || (n == 1 && a == 13 && b == 3 &&  p == 7) || (n == 1 && a == 14 && b == 1 && p == 13) || (n == 1 &&  a == 15 && b == 2 && p == 13) || (n == 1 && a == 17 && b == 3 &&  p == 11) || (n == 1 && a == 18 && b == 1 && p == 17) || (n == 1 &&  a == 19 && b == 2 && p == 17) || (n == 1 && a == 19 && b == 3 &&  p == 13) || (n == 1 && a == 20 && b == 1 && p == 19) || (n == 1 &&  a == 21 && b == 2 && p == 19) || (n == 1 && a == 23 && b == 3 &&  p == 17) || (n == 1 && a == 24 && b == 1 && p == 23) || (n == 1 &&  a == 25 && b == 2 && p == 23) || (n == 1 && a == 25 && b == 3 &&  p == 19) || (n == 1 && a == 26 && b == 4 && p == 2) || (n == 1 &&  a == 27 && b == 4 && p == 3) || (n == 1 && a == 29 && b == 3 &&  p == 23) || (n == 1 && a == 29 && b == 4 && p == 5) || (n == 1 &&  a == 30 && b == 1 && p == 29) || (n == 1 && a == 31 && b == 2 &&  p == 29) || (n == 1 && a == 31 && b == 4 && p == 7) || (n == 1 &&  a == 35 && b == 3 && p == 29) || (n == 1 && a == 35 && b == 4 &&  p == 11) || (n == 1 && a == 37 && b == 4 && p == 13) || (n == 2 &&  a == 2 && b == 1 && p == 3) || (n == 2 && a == 2 && b == 2 &&  p == 2) || (n == 2 && a == 3 && b == 2 && p == 7) || (n == 2 &&  a == 3 && b == 3 && p == 3) || (n == 2 && a == 5 && b == 2 &&  p == 23) || (n == 2 && a == 5 && b == 3 && p == 19) || (n == 3 &&  a == 2 && b == 1 && p == 7) || (n == 3 && a == 2 && b == 3 &&  p == 2) || (n == 3 && a == 3 && b == 4 && p == 3) || (n == 3 &&  a == 5 && b == 5 && p == 5)`

in several minutes (version 13.1 on Windows 10).

Addition.

```
Reduce[a^n == b! + p && 50 >= n > 0 && 40 >= a > 0 && 30 > p > 0 && 
p \[Element] Primes, {a, b, p}, Integers]
```

> `(n == 1 && a == 3 && b == 0 && p == 2) || (n == 1 && a == 3 &&  b == 1 && p == 2) || (n == 1 && a == 4 && b == 0 &&  p == 3) || (n == 1 && a == 4 && b == 1 && p == 3) || (n == 1 &&  a == 4 && b == 2 && p == 2) || (n == 1 && a == 5 && b == 2 &&  p == 3) || (n == 1 && a == 6 && b == 0 && p == 5) || (n == 1 &&  a == 6 && b == 1 && p == 5) || (n == 1 && a == 7 && b == 2 &&  p == 5) || (n == 1 && a == 8 && b == 0 && p == 7) || (n == 1 &&  a == 8 && b == 1 && p == 7) || (n == 1 && a == 8 && b == 3 &&  p == 2) || (n == 1 && a == 9 && b == 2 && p == 7) || (n == 1 &&  a == 9 && b == 3 && p == 3) || (n == 1 && a == 11 && b == 3 &&  p == 5) || (n == 1 && a == 12 && b == 0 && p == 11) || (n == 1 &&  a == 12 && b == 1 && p == 11) || (n == 1 && a == 13 && b == 2 &&  p == 11) || (n == 1 && a == 13 && b == 3 && p == 7) || (n == 1 &&  a == 14 && b == 0 && p == 13) || (n == 1 && a == 14 && b == 1 &&  p == 13) || (n == 1 && a == 15 && b == 2 && p == 13) || (n == 1 &&  a == 17 && b == 3 && p == 11) || (n == 1 && a == 18 && b == 0 &&  p == 17) || (n == 1 && a == 18 && b == 1 && p == 17) || (n == 1 &&  a == 19 && b == 2 && p == 17) || (n == 1 && a == 19 && b == 3 &&  p == 13) || (n == 1 && a == 20 && b == 0 && p == 19) || (n == 1 &&  a == 20 && b == 1 && p == 19) || (n == 1 && a == 21 && b == 2 &&  p == 19) || (n == 1 && a == 23 && b == 3 && p == 17) || (n == 1 &&  a == 24 && b == 0 && p == 23) || (n == 1 && a == 24 && b == 1 &&  p == 23) || (n == 1 && a == 25 && b == 2 && p == 23) || (n == 1 &&  a == 25 && b == 3 && p == 19) || (n == 1 && a == 26 && b == 4 &&  p == 2) || (n == 1 && a == 27 && b == 4 && p == 3) || (n == 1 &&  a == 29 && b == 3 && p == 23) || (n == 1 && a == 29 && b == 4 &&  p == 5) || (n == 1 && a == 30 && b == 0 && p == 29) || (n == 1 &&  a == 30 && b == 1 && p == 29) || (n == 1 && a == 31 && b == 2 &&  p == 29) || (n == 1 && a == 31 && b == 4 && p == 7) || (n == 1 &&  a == 35 && b == 3 && p == 29) || (n == 1 && a == 35 && b == 4 &&  p == 11) || (n == 1 && a == 37 && b == 4 && p == 13) || (n == 2 &&  a == 2 && b == 0 && p == 3) || (n == 2 && a == 2 && b == 1 &&  p == 3) || (n == 2 && a == 2 && b == 2 && p == 2) || (n == 2 &&  a == 3 && b == 2 && p == 7) || (n == 2 && a == 3 && b == 3 &&  p == 3) || (n == 2 && a == 5 && b == 2 && p == 23) || (n == 2 &&  a == 5 && b == 3 && p == 19) || (n == 3 && a == 2 && b == 0 &&  p == 7) || (n == 3 && a == 2 && b == 1 && p == 7) || (n == 3 &&  a == 2 && b == 3 && p == 2) || (n == 3 && a == 3 && b == 4 &&  p == 3) || (n == 3 && a == 5 && b == 5 && p == 5)`

The second answer is longer because of `b==0` cases.

Comment: Note that `n` is omitted in `{a, b, p}`.